# Can anyone explain me calculation formula of this code

Tags: javascript

This code display data in grid format.Can anyone explain how they do this math formula.Since i am new to threejs framework.I never get it how it show the grid use this calculation.

```
let targets = {simple: [], grid: []};
function generateGeometricLayouts() {
for (let i = 0, l = targets.simple.length; i < l; i++) {
        addGridObject(i);
}
}
```

//object

```
function addGridObject(index) {

    let object = new THREE.Object3D();
    object.position.x = ((index % 5) * 400) - 800;
    object.position.y = (-(Math.floor(index / 5) % 5) * 400) + 800;
    object.position.z = (Math.floor(index / 25)) * 1000 - 2000;
    targets.grid.push(object);

}
```

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to answer that. They are calculating a 3D position based on some hardcoded, and unnamed values. Without knowing what those values mean, there is no way to determine what they're doing.

Comment: it creates a 5 x 5 x *n* grid of points

Comment: @Thomas I guess I was wrong :D

Comment: @Thomas how did u say it create 5 x 5 x n ?..I am sorry i never get this formula..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a number of 0 to N and converting it to 2 numbers of a grid (or more commonly a indices of a 2D array) is a common operation

For example

```js
const width = 5
const count = 25;
for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
  const x = i % width;
  const y = Math.floor(i / width);
  console.log(i, 'x:', x, 'y:', y);
}
```

Run the code above and look at the numbers printed in the console. They look like this

```
0 x: 0 y: 0
1 x: 1 y: 0
2 x: 2 y: 0
3 x: 3 y: 0
4 x: 4 y: 0
5 x: 0 y: 1
6 x: 1 y: 1
7 x: 2 y: 1
8 x: 3 y: 1
9 x: 4 y: 1
10 x: 0 y: 2
11 x: 1 y: 2
12 x: 2 y: 2
13 x: 3 y: 2
14 x: 4 y: 2
15 x: 0 y: 3
16 x: 1 y: 3
17 x: 2 y: 3
18 x: 3 y: 3
19 x: 4 y: 3
20 x: 0 y: 4
21 x: 1 y: 4
22 x: 2 y: 4
23 x: 3 y: 4
24 x: 4 y: 4
```

The modulo operator `%` returns the remainder of division so for example `13 % 5` = `3`. `Math.floor` rounds down to the nearest integer value so `13 / 5` = `2.6` and so `Math.floor(2.6)` is just `2`

Note the code above can also be written like this

```js
const width = 5
const count = 25;
for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
  const x = i % width;
  const y = i / width | 0;
  console.log(i, 'x:', x, 'y:', y);
}
```

Above I changed `Math.floor(i / width)` into `i / width | 0`. This takes advantage of the fact that '|' is the "binary or" operator and always converts values into integers. Doing a binary or with 0 does nothing so we're left with just the "converting to integer" part which for positive numbers returns the same values as `Math.floor`.

I prefer this style, it's compact and it's also faster but some programmers prefer using `Math.floor` usually because they don't know about using the `| 0` idiom for rounding down but also because they feel like `Math.floor` is clearer.

This code

```
    object.position.x = ((index % 5) * 400) - 800;
    object.position.y = (-(Math.floor(index / 5) % 5) * 400) + 800;
    object.position.z = (Math.floor(index / 25)) * 1000 - 2000;
```

Is taking that idea one step further. It's making a 3D grid

```js
const width = 5
const count = 125;
for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
  const x = i % width;
  const y = Math.floor(i / width) % width;
  const z = Math.floor(i / width / width);
  log(i, 'x:', x, 'y:', y, 'z:', z);
}

function log(...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement('pre');
  elem.textContent = [...args].join(' ');
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```css
pre { margin: 0; }
```

The rest is just spreading out the grid

Comment: @greggman may i know the calculation convert it into a pyramid form